# "protected virtual" implementation of a "public" interface in AddInBase (Excel)

Tags: c#, excel, interface, vsto

I look at the definition of the `public abstract class AddInBase : EntryPoint` in an Excel 2007 Add-In project. This class is included in the project by default so I have no control over this class.

The interface 
`

```
public interface EntryPoint
{
    void BeginInit();
    void EndInit();
    void FinishInitialization();
    void Initialize();
    void InitializeDataBindings();
    void OnShutdown();
    void OnStartup();
}
```

contains only public methods.

But the realization of `AddInBase` includes `protected virtual` implementation of the `OnShutdown()` method:

```
public abstract class AddInBase : IAddInExtension, IExtension, EntryPoint, ISupportInitialize, IBindableComponent, IComponent, IDisposable
    {
        ///
        protected virtual void OnShutdown();
        protected virtual void OnStartup();
///
    }
```

How this can be?

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: I am confused as to why you are confused.  Why shouldn't the type have those methods?

Comment: @Servy The class has to have those methods. I'm confused that they are marked as "protected virtual" while the interface is "public".  According to my understanding, the compiler shouldn't allow this mismatching combination. But due some unclear reasons, the compiler does compile the code. And I have no idea why.

Comment: @user2668470 - are you sure compiler compiles?

Comment: @AppDeveloper The point is that it DOES compile but only if you are using "Excel 2007 Add-In" template. This AssInBase class is included in the project by default.

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly implement the `EntryPoint` interface, since You are already using a protected method, the class `AddInBase` must satisfy the contract `EntryPoint` hence those are implemented `explicitly`

Example :

```
public interface EntryPoint
{
    void BeginInit();
    void EndInit();
    void FinishInitialization();
    void Initialize();
    void InitializeDataBindings();
    void OnShutdown();
    void OnStartup();
}

public abstract class AddInBase : EntryPoint
{

    void EntryPoint.OnShutdown()
    {
        OnShutdown();
    }

    void EntryPoint.OnStartup()
    {
        OnStartup();
    }

    protected virtual void OnShutdown()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected virtual void OnStartup()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Comment: The situation is a bit trickier. The point is that the compiler in the "Excel 2007 Add-In" project DOES compile the initial class declaration WITHOUT the additional action that you mentioned (i.e., without this additional EXPLICIT implementation wrapping the protected methods). If I open a project different from the "Excel 2007 Add-In", the situation doesn't repeat (i.e., the compiler DOESN'T compile the code without explicit declaration). Maybe the "Excel 2007 Add-In" template does some additional work that is not represented in the main files?